# Función SUM con INNER JOIN en SQL

Tags: sql, sum, inner

Tengo dudas de como hacer un `INNER` o `LEFT` con dos tablas en las cuales no tienen un `id` para hacer referencia.

Mi tabla `impuesto`:

| cod_impuesto | importe |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2000 |
| 5 | 2000 |

Mi tabla `tipoimpuesto`:

| cod_impuesto | cod_tipo_impuesto |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

Y necesito que se vea así:

| cod_impuesto | importe | cod_tipo_impuesto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4000 | 1 |

Comment: no te resulta porque tus tablas no tienen sentido, una de tus tablas debe tener una clave primaria y otra tabla debe tener registros con clave foranea de la primera tabla, los JOIN siempre se hacen de 1 tabla principal y una secundaria que está asociada a la principal por lo que el JOIN se hace con la clave primaria de la tabla principal y la clave foranea

Answer (score 0):

sería un `inner`:

```sql
select im.cod_impuesto, sum(im.importe) importe, tipm.cod_tipo_impuesto
from impuesto im 
join tipoimpuesto timp on im.cod_impuesto = timp.cod_impuesto
group by im.cod_impuesto, tipm.cod_tipo_impuesto
```

Comment: lo plantee asi , pero el importe me da 8000, y no 4000.

Comment: probe con inner y left, pero me sigue duplicando los registros, l oque pasa es que al cod_impuesto tener 2 registros en ambas tablas, en el count de importe me aparece 4 y no 2, por eso me genera el doble.

Comment: Le saque el sum de la subconsulta y funco, gracias !

Comment: es que tienes dos registros jaja en todo caso solo faltaba aplicar un distinct si no querías la suma; saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agrupando los impuestos con el mismo código de impuesto en una subconsulta y haciendo un `INNER JOIN` con la tabla `tipoimpuesto`:

```
SELECT i.cod_impuesto, SUM(i.importe) as importe, ti.cod_tipo_impuesto
FROM (SELECT cod_impuesto, SUM(importe) as importe FROM impuesto GROUP BY cod_impuesto) i
INNER JOIN tipoimpuesto ti ON i.cod_impuesto = ti.cod_impuesto;
```